# Query for MongoDB Associative Arrays

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, aggregation-framework

I am writing a python script to query a MongoDB database. I am in need of assistance with querying, filtering, and parsing data that is stored in associative arrays.

Requirements:

- Query Hostname, Last seen date, Status, and IPV4 Address (other fields not needed)
- Parse the data into a "flat" json format that can be imported into a relational database

Here is the data structure of the data that we are querying:

```
[{"hostnames": [{"type": "ABC", "name": "example.hostname.com"}], "vendor": {"vendor_name": "apple"}, "last_seen": {"$date": 1461123503979}, "status": {"state": "up", "reason": "echo-reply"}, "addresses": {"ipv4": "192.168.1.1"}}]
```

Here is the simpler data structure that I want such that it can be imported into a flat relational database:

```
[{"name": "example.hostname.com", "vendor": "apple", "$date": 1461934503972, "state": "up", "ipv4": "192.168.1.1"}]
```

Here is the code I have started. I am using Aggregation to create aliases for the fields.

I still need to traverse the associative arrays to retrieve the data in the desired format.

```
client = MongoClient(mongo_uri)

db = client[mongo_db]

computers = db['computer'].aggregate([

#Aggregate - RDBMS equivalent to Alias select x as y
#Rename fields to match destination names
       {"$project": {
               "_id":0,
               "u_id":"$id",
               "u_status": "$status",
               "u_vendor":"$vendor",
               "u_addresses": "$addresses",
               "u_hostnames": "$hostnames",
               "u_last_seen": "$last_seen"
       }}
    ])
```

Comment: Is "hostnames" one element list?

Comment: Yep that is an example of a single document in the collection.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. One more question, the "u_last_seen" date is not being returned.

"date": "$last_seen.date"

The date field is encoded. Here is an example of the date field in the database. 

"last_seen" : ISODate("2016-04-29T14:06:17.441Z")

What else do I need to do to return this value? Thanks very much.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Perhaps you should consider to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the "hostnames" array or use the [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) operator to access the "name" field for the element in the array, depending on your server version.

The optimal way is in MongoDB 3.2 using `$arrayElemAt` operator in the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage to return the element in the array which you then set to a variable using the [`$let`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) operator and access the "name" field with dot notation.

```
computers.aggregate([
    {"$project": {
        "name": { 
        "$let": {
            "vars": {"host": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$hostnames", 0]}}, 
            "in": "$$host.name"}
        }, 
        "vendor": "$vendor.vendor_name", 
        "date": "$last_seen.date", 
        "state": "$status.state", 
        "ipv4": "$addresses.ipv4", 
        "_id": 0
    }}
])
```

In old version, you need to deconstruct the array using the `$unwind` operator before `$project`ing your document.

```
computers.aggregate([
    {"$unwind": "$hostnames"},  
    {"$project": {
        "name": "$hostnames.name", 
        "vendor": "$vendor.vendor_name", 
        "date": "$last_seen.date", 
        "state": "$status.state", 
        "ipv4": "$addresses.ipv4", 
        "_id": 0
    }}
])
```